# How to send binary post data via HTTP?

Tags: python, http, post, binary

I already have binary data read from a file. Most of the examples I see online link directly to the file, and upload the whole file. I am looking how to upload the binary data that I already have from another source via HTTP POST in python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alternatively:

```
req = urllib2.Request("http://example.com", data, {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'})
urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

That also shows how you can specify the Content-Type of the data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what online examples you're looking at, but [`urllib2.urlopen`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) takes the *data* to post as a chunk of data and not a file at all.

Comment: Example: http://www.2maomao.com/blog/python-http-post-a-binary-file-using-urllib2/

Comment: I'll have to take a network sniff. The server that I am POST'ing to is issuing a 400 Bad Request when I try that.

Comment: Okay, so that example reads the data from a file into `png_data`. If you already have the data in memory, just use that in the calls to `urllib2`.