# Using requests to send byte-array to webservice using http post

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, arrays, python-requests

Currently I'm trying to send a byte-array to a webservice, but i get the error message, that a bytearray is not serializeable:

> TypeError: bytearray(b'') is not JSON serializable

I'm using the following code

Sending the requests

```
# Set blob
with open('demo-file.txt') as file:
    f = file.read()
    b = bytearray(f)
    print a.set_data('5cb9bc4d-c0fd-40ab-8b74-4e62b50d8966', b)
```

Set_Data method:

```
def set_data(self, path, data):
    """
    Save data in

    Parameter
    --------
    path (str): Path as string
    data (bytearray): Data as bytearray
    """

    result = requests.post(self.url + '/set', json = { 'path': path, 'data': data})

    # Check status and token
    if result.status_code == 200:
        return result.text
```

What am I doing wrong, do I have to use some other methods for sending bytearrays?

Thank you all a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really need json, you have to encode your binary data. See: [Base64 encoding in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908287/base64-encoding-in-python-3)

An alternative: [How to send binary post data via HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864803/how-to-send-binary-post-data-via-http)

Comment: Yep, I normally use Newtonsoft json in c# and that make the base64 conversion automatically. Thank you, did not know that before!